# Openpyxl write list of numeric data: Value error (Invalid column index)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm working on a script to calculate the shortest distance between each point of one set and any point of another set.

When executing this, I get the folowiwng error:
**ValueError: Invalid column index 18279**

I guess it's caused by the write part:

```
wb = Workbook(write_only = True) 
ws = wb.create_sheet() 

ws.append(output) 
wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Currently this is my full code: https://pastebin.com/UJJzM3Xm

I've been trying to limit the number of companypoints to 1000, but even that's not working...

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect your rows are too wide but your code is too convoluted for me to debug.

Comment: Thanks Charlie!
What do you mean with 'rows too wide'? 
thx again!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, so I thought it might be useful sharing it!

I think openpyxl is limiting the number of colums to 18279. 
- I changed the range of the output to ensure 10.000 colums were written to excel
- I ran the script 8 times
- I was able to get all the 73.000 values

Thanks for helping me!